# Using threads with separate Graphics classes

Tags: multithreading, loops

I am writing a graphics program however I am having trouble calling for the thread to start in the main and getting it to run in the separate class. My main class looks like the following..

```
package shooter;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ShooterRunner extends JFrame {


   public ShooterRunner()
   {
       super("Shooter Game");
       setSize(600,600);
       setBackground(Color.black);
       setResizable(false);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       getContentPane().add(new Shooter());
       setFocusable(true);
       setVisible(true);

   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ShooterRunner test = new ShooterRunner();
       Thread thread = new Thread(new Shooter());
   }

}
```

I am aware that I am creating a new instance of shooter when I create the thread however I get an error if I try create a Shooter object above and use it for both getContentPane.add() and as the parameters of creating the thread.

Comment: Could you give more info on the `Shooter` class and Could you explain "use it for both getContentPane.add() " clearly?

Comment: Im trying to add a shooter object to the screen. I am doing this by saying getContentPane().add(new Shooter()). However i want to start a Thread in this same Shooter class. What the Shooter class does is not very relevant it just implements Runnable and has the required run method. Im sorry if im not being descriptive enough